# how to use frame animation in android

Tags: android, animation, frame

hi im fairly new to android i have an activity using a frame animation but everytime it force closes. this is the logcat

```
12-16 19:22:38.045  28183-28183/com.martinsapp.socialstories E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ 
Out of   memory on a 13271056-byte allocation.

12-16 19:22:38.055  28183-28183/com.martinsapp.socialstories E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.martinsapp.socialstories/com.martinsapp.socialstories.duckActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2274)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5153)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at
```

is this just saying the images are too big?

@weston yes i am this is the drawable.xml file im using

```
<animation-list
android:id="@+id/movingduck"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/movingduck1" android:duration="250"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/movingduck2" android:duration="250"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/movingduck3" android:duration="250"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/movingduck4" android:duration="250"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/movingduck5" android:duration="250"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/movingduck6" android:duration="250"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/movingduck7" android:duration="250"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/movingduck8" android:duration="250"/>
```

Comment: Yes, are you using a drawable xml file for this anim? If so post it.

Comment: @weston yes i am, here is the drawable.xml

Comment: @weston sorry if this is another question and should have its own thread but it says the drawables xml must be defined as a background, does that mean i could use it on the background of a layout? eg linear, frame or relative layout with frameanimation at android:background or must it be attached to an imageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to scale images and framerates back pretty aggressively to get something that will function without exception on devices back to Froyo.  Think more in the range of 240x320 with around 10 frames. that's about 300k bytes per image.  Don't think you're in the clear cause the png is only 24K on disk, the memory consumed per frame is the uncompressed size (W x H x 4bytes/pix).

Comment: my images are around 53kb uncompressed 480x768

Comment: 480 * 768 * 4 (bytes/pix for truecolor) = 1,474,560 bytes per image in memory which seems to match your memory exception pretty closely.

Comment: okay cool thanks for the reply, i just changed my approach and got the same result so if i dont aim back as far as froyo can i keep my images? api 11 and above? or is there something better you could point me towards? without blowing out my infant little android brains lol @dangVarmit

Comment: okay have just scaled all my 8 images to 120x190 and noticed the decompressed size pops up on saving and is dramatically less once saved had to rip out some existing stuff i had but it is now working thank you,